# Checking if files are empty or not through Linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to check with bash script if files with same extensions in a directory empty or not and print out the name of the file if it is not empty.

Comment: Honestly I have not tried anything since I do not have much experience with shell script. I can write something to check only a specific file but have no idea how to check 500+ files with a certain extension and print out the name of the files which are not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job for `find` (GNU `find` precisely), assuming the extension to match is `.txt`, and directory to check is `/directory`:

```
find /directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -not -empty
```

Recursively:

```
find /directory -type f -name '*.txt' -not -empty
```

---

Slow shell-way, using `for` to iterate over the files, and `test` (`[`) to check the conditions:

```
for f in /directory/*.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ -s "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

Recursively, with `bash`'s `globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in /directory/**/*.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ -s "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: The "slow shell-way" could be made a bit shorter with Bash-specific syntax `for f in /directory/*.txt; do [[ -f $f && -s $f ]] && echo "$f"; done`.  I would not be surprised (though I have not tested) if this "slow" solution turns out to be faster for directories with reasonably low file count, as the overhead of launching an external command is not negligible.

Comment: @Fred hmmmm...thought about that, but the problem is another slower portion i.e. iterating over files using `for` is still there so `find` should be the way to go...

Comment: @heemayl  In most cases it will not matter, so I would go with whatever one is more comfortable with, and if performance is an issue I would test on representative data to see if there are significant differences.  I would not discount the pure-shell solution without testing first by assuming performance would be worse.